# Inline tag highlighing code too obnoxious?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, design

To me, it appears as if the tag inline highlighting is too intrusive / obnoxious.  It breaks up the spacing-below of the line it's placed on (due to the height.)  Perhaps the font in an inline tag should have a slightly shorter line-height or font-size to compensate for this, to prevent it breaking up paragraphs?

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: I agree, and am not sure why this got so many downvotes. See [this post](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/4035/3062) for an example of how bad it can look, and how difficult it can make a post to read.

Comment: @Sterno, heh, you have a point, the styles used on Gaming exacerbate this problem, since the actual height of the tag "widget" appears to be shorter than on the Big Three. I don't know exactly which meta site on the network is competent to address this issue, so maybe it's appropriate here. In the meantime, you can somewhat alleviate the problem in your specific Meta Gaming question by using taller paragraph breaks. I opened an account there to submit an edit request as a proposal, but I forgot the rep requirements ;p

Answer (score 2):

The inline tag links expose the `post-tag` class, which resolves to:

```
background-color: #E7E7E7;
border-bottom: 1px solid #626262;
border-right: 1px solid #979797;
color: #6F6F6F;
font-size: 90%;
line-height: 2.4;
margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
padding: 3px 4px;
text-decoration: none;
white-space: nowrap;
```

You can create a [user stylesheet](http://webdesign.about.com/od/userstylesheets/User_Style_Sheets.htm) or install a browser add-on like [Stylish](http://userstyles.org/stylish) to customize the CSS above as you see fit.

Comment: While it's nice that this is possible for a programmer-type who wants to fix it just for themselves, it doesn't really help the average user on a site like Gaming.StackExchange or any of the other non-technical SEs.

Comment: This looks like an answer one might find on the non-meta SO site.

Comment: @Sterno - Could someone make a plug-in, browser extension, or Stack App that adjusts the CSS?  Seems like an overkill, but without the SE developers considering this a high priority, it's probably the best/only solution.

Comment: @jmort253 That sort of solution fixes it for me, or the 3 other people from Gaming.SE who happen to find their way here, but it really isn't a fix for the general user.

Comment: Wouldn't a plug-in or app work for other users if it were well-documented and easy to install? Think Chrome or Firefox Add-on. They are targeted at end-users.